# Can't install pip packages

Tags: python

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssepw.png)

Hey everyone!
I'm having this error (image above) for a long time and nothing here can solve it for me.
pip does this error for every package I try to install (this time pynput).
I have python 3.8.2 and pip is up to date.
I tried doing the  `--default-timeout=1000` thing and it doesn't work too.
Python 3.8.2 is in PATH too.
pip version is 19.2.3.

The error: `C:\Users\LikeV>pip install pynput --user --upgrade Collecting pynput WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pynput/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pynput/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pynput/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pynput/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pynput/ ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pynput (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pynput`

Comment: what does `pip --version` returns ? It looks like you have mulitple pip and it uses the older `pip`  version.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include your code as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image. Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

try a couple of options:

```
pip install pynput --user --upgrade
```

usually works for me.